# Sum multiple attributes in array of objects

Tags: arrays, ruby

I understand that in ruby we can sum the elements in an array like this

```
[1,2,3].sum 
[<Object a: 1>, <Object a:2>].sum(&:a)
```

How about running a sum on multiple attributes in the array of objects. For example:

```
arr = [<Object a:1, b:2, ..., n:10>, <Object a:1, b:2, ..., n:10>, ... <nth Object>]
```

What is the most efficient way to get the sum of multiple attributes a, b, ... n?

I have tried these methods:

```
sum_a = arr.sum(&:a)
sum_b = arr.sum(&:b)
```

```
a, b = 0, 0
arr.each do |obj|
  a += obj.a
  b += obj.b
end
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own method for this:

```
def sum_multiple(arr, *keys)
  arr.each_with_object(keys.zip([0] * keys.size).to_h) do |o,obj|
    keys.each {|k| obj[k] += o.public_send(k)}
  end
end
```

Usage as:

```
class A 
  attr_reader :a,:b,:c 

  def initialize(a,b,c)
    @a,@b,@c = a,b,c
  end 
end 

arr = 10.times.map {|i| A.new(i,i*2,i*3)}

sum_multiple(arr,:a)
#=> {:a=>45}
sum_multiple(arr,:a,:b)
#=> {:a=>45, :b=>90}
sum_multiple(arr,:a,:b,:c)
#=> {:a=>45, :b=>90, :c=>135}
"Sum of everything: #{sum_multiple(arr,:a,:b,:c).sum(&:last)}" 
#=> "Sum of everything: 270"
```

[Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/SumMultiple)

**Note:** If this is rails then you should look into combinations of group by and sum and put this on the database.

Comment: how have you defined the A class here?

Comment: @lacostenycoder while the definition of the class isn't all that important since the methods `#a`, `#b`, and `#c` could be antyhing it does lend to reproducibility I have added the definition

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum only some of the key values you can do:

```
[{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}].flat_map{|h| h.slice(:a, :b).values}.sum
```

Or if you want to sum all values then just

```
[{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}].flat_map(&:values).sum
```

For objects who might not be hashes

```
arr.sum {|o| [:a, :b, :c].sum{ |key| o.send key} }
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something more like `a.reduce {|memo,h| memo.merge(h) { |_,o,n| o + n }}`

Comment: But every object does not have merge method.

Comment: @HazhirDerakhshi not every object has a values method either

Comment: @engineersmnky Exactly.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks I updated again. Your versions is more robust but I may have not gotten clear what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: @lacostenycoder yeah it is a bit unclear because this *"How about running a sum on multiple attributes in the array of objects"* can have multiple interpretations including an interim per pass sum, but the code examples seem more like a sum per attribute either way +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by creating an array of instances.

```
class C
  def initialize(a,b,c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end
end
```

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]].map { |a| C.new(*a) }
  #=> [#<C:0x00005a4282c2d980 @a=1, @b=2, @c=3>,
  #    #<C:0x00005a4282c2d5c0 @a=4, @b=5, @c=6>,
  #    #<C:0x00005a4282c2d3b8 @a=7, @b=8, @c=9>]
```

then

```
ivs = arr.first.instance_variables
  #=> [:@a, :@b, :@c]
arr.map { |i| ivs.map { |v| i.instance_variable_get(v) } }. 
    transpose.
    map(&:sum)
 #=> [12, 15, 18]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.map { |i| ivs.map { |v| i.instance_variable_get(v) } }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] 
b = a.transpose
  #=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]] 
c = b.map(&:sum) 
  #=> [12, 15, 18]
```

If labels are desired:

```
ivs = arr.first.instance_variables
ivs.zip(arr.map {|i| ivs.map {|v| i.instance_variable_get(v)}}. 
            transpose.
            map(&:sum)).
    to_h
  #=> {:@a=>12, :@b=>15, :@c=>18}
```

If only sums of some instance variables were desired, say `@a` and `@c`, just change `ivs`:

```
ivs = [:@a, :@c]
ivs.zip(arr.map {|i| ivs.map {|v| i.instance_variable_get(v)}}. 
            transpose.
            map(&:sum)).
    to_h
  #=> {:@a=>12, :@c=>18}
```